# Simple basic physics question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, time, acceleration, projectile

I was doing my physics homework, and have found the answer, but was curious to know if it could be done differently. This is not a question for homework but I would just like someone to clarify why the 2 answers I found are different (I know the correct one though).

The question is as follows:

A stone is projected vertically upwards from the ground with an initial velocity of $80$ $m/s$. Find the greatest height and the time taken for this height to be reached. When will the stone be $96$  $m$ above the ground.

Solution of the first part:

$$v^2=u^2+2as$$
$$0=80^2-2(9.8)s$$
$$0=6400-19.6s$$
$$s=326.531 $$

also

$$v=u+at$$
$$0=80-9.8t$$
$$t=8.163$$

Solution for the second part:

$$s=ut+\frac{at^2}{2}$$
$$96=80t-4.9t^2$$
$$4.9t^2-80t+96$$

$$t=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
$$t=\frac{80 \pm \sqrt{4518.4}}{9.8}$$

$$t= 1.304 $$

or

$$t= 15.02$$

These are the two timings at which the stone is at 96 m. However the values for $u,v,a,s$ are all for the journey upwards. So, I tried calculating it for the journey downwards. I used the following values:

$$u=0,a=9.8,s=326.531-96=230.531$$

The results were:

$$s=ut+\frac{at^2}{2}$$
$$230.531=4.9t^2$$
$$t^2=47.047$$
$$t=\sqrt{47.047}=6.859$$

This is obviously wrong because it takes 8.163 s to reach the maximum point. My question is where did I go wrong and why is this method wrong to use. Thanks.

Comment: While calculating the journey downwards, is $u=0$?

Comment: You are calculating the time to reach the bottom from 230,531 meters, which is not the top. The velocity at that point is not zero. it is only zero at the top.

Comment: @PeterR This is not what I am calculating. I am trying to find the time the stone takes to travel 230.531 metres from the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is sound but sometimes a velocity time graph might help?

[image]

There is nothing new in this graph as the constant acceleration kinematic equations that you using are derived from it.

In your second method you have forgotten that it took time ($= 8.163$) seconds to reach the maximum height so the total time is $6.859 + 8.163 = 15.02$ seconds which is the same value as you got before when solving the quadratic.

This tells you that as long as you set up the equations correctly they are good for going up and going down.

Comment: This is true, I forgot that this is only the journey downwards. Thanks

Comment: One last point.  The motion up and down is symmetrical so once you have the time to first reach $96$ m you when it reaches that height.  It is twice the time to reach maximum height (the time to hit the ground) minus the time taken to first reach $96$ m. Try it.

Comment: Sorry, it is not very clear what this method is used to calculate. Can  you please explain. Maybe using a formula (variables) could make it easier. I am sorry for taking your time on such basic stuff.

Comment: The stone is thrown upwards and it took $1.30$ seconds to reach a height of $96$ m.  The stone then takes $8.16$ s to reach its maximum height.  Then it takes a total time of $15.02$ s to again reach a height of $96$ m.  From this height it will take $1.30$ s to reach the ground which would happen after a total the total time of $2\times 8.16 = 16.32$ s has elapsed.  What I tried to explain was that $16.32 - 1.30 = 15.02$ s is the time to reach $96$ m.